# How to make a Python function sleep some time while the rest of the game continues?

Tags: python, time, pygame, sleep

This is what I tried:

```
if len(wormCoords) > 2:
    time.sleep(4)
    del wormCoords[-1]
```

but then the whole game (I'm doing a simple "snake" game) sleeps for 4 seconds before removing the last part of the snake. The plan is to each 4 seconds remove the last part of the snake so that you constantly have to eat apples(when you do, the snake grows by one) otherwise you'll die (the snake gets hungry and starves).

The full code is to be find here: http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter6.html
but I am doing some changes with it.

Comment: It might be a good idea to mention explicitly that you are using pygame. I suggest you add the pygame tag.

Comment: @mplourde I think using a multithreaded aproche for this problem is not the way to go. To many problems, no advantages...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right thing to do here is set a timer event using this in the setup code (after the line `HEAD = 0`)

```
SHRINKSNAKE = pygame.USEREVENT+0
```

this goes in the `runGame` function after `direction = RIGHT`

```
pygame.time.set_timer(SHRINKSNAKE, 4*1000)
```

and this in the event handling loop in `runGame` before the line `elif event.type == KEYDOWN:` the `elif`s should line up

```
elif event.type == SHRINKSNAKE:
  if len(wormCoords) > 2:
    del wormCoords[-1]
```

For more details check the documentation on [`pygame.time.set_timer`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a little new with Python. What is the setup code? Thanks for taking your time :)

Comment: It says when I run it "There's an error in your program: expected an indented block".. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @SebastianAnving if you haven't yet figured it out, I've edited the answer to include specifics on where it should go relative to the code you linked to in the question

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [pygame.time.set_timer](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) function. This allows you to cause an event to be triggered every few milliseconds that you can handle with your typical event handling mechanism (just like you handle mouse move, keyboard, draw, etc). Read the [pygame.event](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) docs for more info on handling the events.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want the rest of your application to pause when calling "sleep", you'll need to use threads (see http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html).  Since the "wormCoords" variable will need to be shared between threads, you'll need to take proper care when updating it to avoid a race condition.

Comment: while using the threading module could be made to work, it is much more difficult than using a pygame timer